# How to separate date and time example: 12/25/17 0:00 in R?

Tags: r, datetime, date-formatting

How do I separate date and time into 2 different variables if `the_date` column is as follows:

[image: data set image for reference]

```
the_date
12/25/17 0:00
```

How can I separately retrieve

- year as 2017,
- month as 12 or December,
- Date as 12, and
- time as 0.00 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting to DateTime, then we extract each of the components

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(v1 = mdy_hm(v1), 
           Year = year(v1),
           Month = month(v1), 
           Date = day(v1), 
           time = format(v1, "%H:%M:%S"))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#   v1                   Year Month  Date time    
#   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>   
#1 2017-12-25 00:00:00  2017    12    25 00:00:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(v1 = "12/25/17 0:00")
```

Comment: How do I create separate columns and add them in data frame?
Snapshot of my data frame : http://prntscr.com/ncvywj
And add Year, Month, Date and Time column names to the data frame : daily_logs

Comment: @user1884763  If  `df1` is the data.frame as showed in the `data`, use `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(..`